# Starting solr replication at custom time

Tags: solr, replication, master-slave

I am new to solr. I am reading replication [doc](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrReplication) and I am wondering is there a way to set replication exact hour for example in Friday in 22:33:44. I can set **Interval in which the slave should poll master** (according to the documentation) but if I set it to 24 hours and start first replication in 11:22:33 in the morning next starts at the middle of the night. Am I doing something wrong? I am using solr 5.2.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to control the time at which replication should happen, I would suggest to disable polling and make use of replication REST API with an external scheduler.

We use this also to do some validations also on master before let slave replicate which would impact end user.